# Lcov: can not collect branch coverage statistics

Tags: c, testing, branch, code-coverage, lcov

I used the `lcov` to create coverage information in my project. But I only can get line coverage and function coverage statistics information.

```
lcov version:1.10, gcov version:4.4.5
```

The commands I used is:

```
 lcov -d $OSPL_HOME/src -d $OSPL_OUTER_HOME/src  -c -o /work/li/log/lcov-raw.info

lcov -r /work/li/log/lcov-raw.info "*.ll" "*.yy" "*.yy.c" yaccpar "TAO161*" "/usr/include/*"  "*/testsuite/*" -o /work/li/log/lcov.info
```

After these two commands, I got the results is:

```
Deleted 23 files

Writing data to /work/li/log/lcov.info

Summary coverage rate:

  lines......: 45.4% (65087 of 143496 lines)

   functions..: 46.1% (5575 of 12102 functions)

  **branches...: no data found**
```

So there were no branches coverage results. Why? So what happened? And how can this happen?  I am confused here.

After the first command, I got lots of warnings like these:

```
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#accum.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#at.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#autodef.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#copyof.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#debug.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#define.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#dump.c.gcov in .gcno file,skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#error.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#expand.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#expr.c.gcov in .gcno file,skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#if.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#include.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#io.c.gcov in .gcno file, s kipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#is.c.gcov in .gcno file, s kipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#line.c.gcov in .gcno file,skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#pragma.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#preprocess.c.gcov in .gcnofile, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#set.c.gcov in .gcno file,skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#sharp.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#symtbl.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#undef.c.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
 geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for ..#..#code#while.c.gcov in .gcno file , skipping file!
```

Comment: Please add the answer as an answer your own question. I found it very helpful.

Comment: I've added a community wiki answer below. If the author ever returns to this question, he/she can add their own answer and bask in the rewards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating branch coverage data for lcov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360167/generating-branch-coverage-data-for-lcov)

Answer (score 34):

I got the email from Peter Oberparleiter, the author of geninfo. I got the answer as following.

LCOV 1.10 has branch coverage disabled per default. You can enable it by modifying the lcovrc file (see `man lcovrc`) or by specifying `--rc lcov_branch_coverage=1` when running `lcov/genhtml`.

If you're not using LCOV 1.10 and still don't get branch coverage, it may be that you're version of GCC does not provide this information.

(*The above answer was erroneously added to the question by [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823629/user1823629).*)

Answer (score 13):

the solution given above :

```
--rc lcov_branch_coverage=1
```

used both for lcov and genhtml, worked for me.